# Isekai manhwa about a guy who is reborn as a girl, along with three other women who reincarnate as guys

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This guy torments(?) them, so they ask for revenge in the next life. And the guy is reborn as a girl with brown hair, and she's a maid. And the three women are reborn as men. The first man has an affair with another maid that the protagonist witnesses, and she pretends to be a blanket monster.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You tagged this as `isekai`, so did the four main characters originally live in the real world, and then find themselves reborn into a fantasy world? Or did they always live in a fantasy world?

Answer (score 2):

Fairly sure this is ***[The Tyrant's Whereabouts](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-tyrants-whereabouts)***.

[image]

> Once upon a time, there was a beautiful king who was merciless and greedy. Upon taking a look at his life record, God shook his head. God asked the three women who suffered greatly because of the king, “What punishment would you like him to receive?” Then, the three women, glancing at one another, answered all at once. “Please send all of us back to Earth.”

God asks three women, who suffered due to the tyranny of a cruel king, what punishment they'd like him to inflict upon him. The women ask for all four of them (including the king) to be sent back to Earth, and for some of the king's key attributes to be transferred to them.

The first woman asks for the king's handsome face to be taken from him and given to her. The second woman asks for the king's swordsmanship skill (which he used to kill her father and brother) to be taken from him and given to her. And the third woman asks for the king's steel heart to be taken from him and given to her.

As a result of all this, the king is reincarnated as a maid with brown hair, while the three women who suffered under him are reincarnated as noblemen.

Early on in the story, there's a scene where the maid witnesses a nighttime rendezvous between one of the noblemen and another maid. When the nobleman notices her, she wraps a shaul around her head and runs away, in an attempt to avoid being recognised.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Aki - If anyone correctly identifies the manhwa you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.